# Eliminating use of binary_function and result_type

Tags: c++11, c++17, std-function, resulttype

I am trying to update an abandoned open source library to C++11 and 17. It uses `std::binary_function` and its `result_type` in a way I am not sure how to remove. These features were deprecated in C++11 and removed in 17.

First, I've simply removed `std::binary_function` (and `std::unary_function`) from [this](https://github.com/ramcdona/Pinocchio/blob/master/Pinocchio/mathutils.h#L44).

Next, I'm unsure how to eliminate the use of result_type in places like [this](https://github.com/ramcdona/Pinocchio/blob/master/Pinocchio/vector.h#L247).

```cpp
      template<class R, int D, class F>
        static Vector<typename F::result_type, D> apply(const F &func, const VRD &v)
        {
            Vector<typename F::result_type, D> out;
            _apply(func, v, out);
            return out;
        }
```

I tried replacing `Vector<typename F::result_type, D>` with `auto`, but my compiler (currently set to C++11) complained that `auto` for return types is introduced in C++14.

`F` is a generic functor. How can I re-write the above code when I don't know what `result_type` is?

Comment: You would need something like `decltype(std::declval<F>()(std::declval<VRD>()))`.

Comment: Thanks @n.m.couldbeanAI I think I made progress there.  That routine calls another (line 52 of the file) that looks like this...

    template<class F> Vector<typename F::result_type, Dim> apply(const F &func) const
      { return VO::apply(func, *this); }


Which I attempt to convert to decltype/declval like this:

    template<class F> decltype( std::declval<F>()( std::declval<Self>() ) ) apply(const F &func) const
      { return VO::apply(func, *this); }


But I'm still having troubles.

Comment: Assuming `VO::apply` returns the right `Vector`, just make it `template <typename F> auto apply(...)` and let the compiler figure out the return type from the `return` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestions, I was eventually able to get it to work.  I did use C++17 features, so this version won't work on C++11.

The result is posted [here](https://github.com/ramcdona/Pinocchio/commit/b17cefe1455b7922a9ea61867d6e140ef0ea3e71).  There ended up being a number of techniques required -- depending on whether result_type appeared as a return type, as an argument type, or as a variable type inside the function.  Two of these were illustrated in the sample above.

The above example ends up looking like this...

```cpp
      template<class R, int D, class F>
        static decltype(auto) apply(const F &func, const VRD &v)
        {
            Vector< decltype( func( v[0] ) ), D > out;
            _apply(func, v, out);
            return out;
        }
```